# vim how to set good indet without syntax highlighting?

Tags: vim, syntax, syntax-highlighting

I have mapped <kbd>F8</kbd> to `:set syntax=off<cr>`.

I like editing without syntax highlighting, but if I switch syntax off, my indent rules also switched off. How can I have good indent without syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If vim autoindent is ok for you , you can

```
set autoindent
```

after you "syntax off".

On the other hand, if you use your own index function. Try to run following command, which may help.

```
set indentexpr=<your function>
```

Or check the indent function by:

```
set indentexpr?
```

and reset it to the result after "syntax off"

Comment: +1 for the great coverage, and no @RusAlex, they are independent.

Comment: They should be independent, or at least on my vim73 on windows/Linux platform. Are you using "vi" or "vim"? They are not the same thing. If it is possible, it is worth to update to the latest vim73.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to map that key to

```
:syntax off
```

Note that `syntax` is a command, and `off` an argument. You were setting the `syntax` option to the type `off` and consequentially affecting the indent rules.

Check `:h :syntax` and `:h 'syntax'` to read more.

Comment: :set syntax=off work too but only for current buffer. but my question is about indent without syntax hightlight

Comment: Sorry @RusAlex, but it works for me. Also, notice the help says that if you want to set the *syntax* option off, set it to `OFF` and not `off`, in the latter case you'd be setting the syntax to files of kind *off*. The problem might be coming from somewhere else. If what @winterTTr posted didn't help, try reviewing your settings and *autocommands*.